# Is it possible to save the sorting order of rows and columns of Kendo UI pivot Grid?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, grid, pivot, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am new to kendo UI stuff, I am using the Kendo Pivot Grid. As per my client requirement I have saved the rows and columns state of kendo Pivot Grid, but he also want to save the sorting order of rows and columns. I am following this http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/pivotgrid/index demo of Pivot Grid.

I am getting the columns of Grid like this:-

```
var datasource1 = $("#pivotgrid").data("kendoPivotGrid").dataSource;
var Columns = datasource1._columns;

var CommaSapratedListOfColumns = "";
for (var i = 0; i < Columns.length; i++) {
    debugger;
    var SingleColumn = Columns[i].name;
    CommaSapratedListOfColumns += SingleColumn + ",";
}
CommaSapratedListOfColumns = CommaSapratedListOfColumns.replace(/,\s*$/, "");
```

and dong same for the rows, and then save them to a text file and at the time of initializing the grid I just get the saved list of column and rows from the files and put them in gird configuration dynamically like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("ReadFile","PivoteGrid")'+'?file1=true&file2=true',
    type: 'get',
    async:false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        debugger;
        if (data.file1!="") {
            savedColumns = data.file1.split(',');
        }
        if (data.file2 != "")
        {
            savedRows = data.file2.split(',');
        }                        


        var pivotgrid = $("#pivotgrid").kendoPivotGrid({
                filterable: true,
                sortable: true,
                columnWidth: 200,
                height: 580,
                dataSource: {
                    type: "xmla",
                    columns: savedColumns,//List of Saved Column here
                    rows: savedRows,//list of saved rows here
```

now i need to save the sorting order too, is this possible to save get the sorting order of Kendo UI pivot grid rows and columns, if yes then how if no then why not? any suggestion will be appreciated!! if you need any more explanation I am here!! thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3):

First don't use properties prefixed with underscore like *datasource._columns* because they are internal properties and they could change in future version, use the public API instead like *dataSource.columns()*. See [Docs](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource)

In order to save columns and rows:

```
var columnsPivotCurrent = [];
var rowsPivotCurrent = [];
columnsPivotCurrent = dataSource.columns();
rowsPivotCurrent = dataSource.rows();

var pivotgrid = $("#pivotgrid").kendoPivotGrid({
    filterable: true,
    sortable: true,
    columnWidth: 200,
    height: 580,
    dataSource: {
        type: "xmla",
        columns: columnsPivotCurrent,//List of Saved Column here
        rows: rowsPivotCurrent,//list of saved rows here
..
```

For the sorting this cannot be achieved now because PivotGrid lack this feature [Persist State Demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/persist-state) which is available for Grid component